# Filtering 1 List View multiple ways, depending on user logged in

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In SharePoint 2013, I have created a list that needs dynamic filtering.

For example: I need **one** view that when user2 or user3 are viewing the list, they will only see the files that have their names in the "Provider" field from the list.

Yet when User1, or any other user, is logged in they will see everything within the list (though using the same fields is fine).

Is this possible to do within **one** view?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your discription User1 is an admin user ? if yes then you can carete a view using the filter where Provider is equal to [Me]

So when User 2 is logged in then he/she can see only those records which are available to them as a provider. and same for user3.

But when User 1 which is an admiistrator in that case he can see all the records from allitems view.

Thanks

Comment: SigarDave, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, we are looking to have ALL users only use **one** view. In your example, there would be two views: View1 for User2 and User3, and AllItems for all other users. Any idea how to accomplish this within 1 view? Also, to answer your question, all other users will be admins on the list. Thanks!